# TTL in Elasticsearch doesn't working

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping, kibana, ttl

I set TTL in templates like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/keyword' -d '
{
  "template": "keyword*",
    "mappings": {
       "fluentd": {
          "_source": {
             "compress": true
          },
          "_ttl": {
            "enabled": true,
            "default": "120d"
          },
          "properties": {
           ....
          }   
       }
    }
}'
```

And when I check mapping I get this:

```
 "keyword-2016.02.16": {
  "mappings": {
     "fluentd": {
        "_all": {
           "enabled": false
        },
        "_ttl": {
           "enabled": true,
           "default": 10368000000
        },
        "_source": {
           "compress": true
        },
        "properties": {
           .....
        }
     }
  }
```

But indices are not deleted after ttl expires. Do you know maybe what can be a problem?

Also in Kibana I get this:

[Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9QWc.png)

Answer (score 0):

TTL controls the document expiration, not index. It means indexes will never be deleted by TTL.